# Cortana channel user/bot messages doesn't appear in App insights and analytics

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I have noticed a weird issue wherein the messages are not logged in the Application insights when the conversation happens from Cortana channel. Other channels are logged.

The bot is built using C# and working properly and all, just that the `Activity` events are not getting logged in App insights while using from **cortana**, thus not showing in Analytics as well. I had quite a few conversations from cortana channel.

[image]

None in Application insights analytics as well.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the `Activity` events are not getting logged in App insights while using from **cortana**

I enabled webchat, Direct Line and Cortana channels, and did a test. I can reproduce the issue, the Activity events can be logged in Application insights for webchat and Direct Line channel, but it seems not log Activity events from Cortana channel.

[image]

***Query result:*** *(in **Channel ID** field, we can find activity from **directline** channel are logged, but no activity from Cortana channel is logged)*

[image]

If possible, you can give a feedback on [“Azure Bot Service Customer Feedback site”](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/562027-azure-bot-service) or [github issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues) to report it.

Besides, if you’d like to trace the conversation happens from Cortana channel, you can try to query data from **dependencies**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fei Han for confirming the issue. Have raised a [git hub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4739). Thanks!